# Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] for XAMPP and Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc, xampp

I am using XAMPP server and Eclipse IDE for running a hibernate program. But I am getting the following error:

> **Apr 21, 2017 12:46:38 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
>       INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.8.Final}
>       Apr 21, 2017 12:46:38 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment 
>       INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
>       Apr 21, 2017 12:46:38 PM
>       org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager 
>       
>       INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
>       Apr 21, 2017 12:46:39 PM
>
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderI
>       mpl configure
>       WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for 
>       production use!)
>       Failed to create sessionFactory 
>       object.org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create 
>       requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
>       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>       at ManageEmployee.main(ManageEmployee.java:18)
>       Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create 
>       requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(A
>       bstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
>       at ManageEmployee.main(ManageEmployee.java:15)
>       Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
>       at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:348)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.loadDriverIfPossible(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:160)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:116)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:100)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259)
>       ... 14 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
>       at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:336)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:345)
>       ... 26 more**

Need to know the root cause of this error or possible reasons for this error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is under two folds of stack-trace, looks like your MySQL Connector/J driver jar is not available on Classpath.

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Place the required JAR file in the **CLASSPATH** and retry, issue should be fixed. Adding the jar to CLASSPATH should resolve the issue.

If you are using `maven`, then make sure that you add the necessary dependency in your `pom.xml` file.